# SQL Server ISNUMERIC() Clarification

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a table X with a list of accountNo's. This field(accoutNo) is a nvarchar(8).
Now issue here is sometimes we get characters in this field as well and I want to convert it into bigint.

Sorry I'am not able to put this in a table format here.

I'am able to check if a accountNo is a numeric value or not:

```
select x.accountNo from x where ISNUMERIC(x.accountNo)=1
```

but when I try to only convert the values if an accountNo is numeric, I still can't, I'm confused:

```
select x.accountNo, convert(bigint,x.accountNo) from x where ISNUMERIC(x.accountNo)=1
```

**The specific error I'm receiving:**

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type
>   nvarchar to bigint.

### Sample Data

```
accountNo  A0001001  A0001002  A0001003  /0005856  !0005046  ~0005872     A.005698 A/005623 A./00578 ./214536
```

Comment: I tried that but I don't get error

Comment: @FLICKER please try out all the accountNo's I have mentioned above. one of them is not able to convert. I'm not able to format it in a tabular format.

Comment: I used all account and still not getting error. what is the version of your sql-server?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: I tried on SQL 2012 and 2014. Still not getting error. This is interesting to figure out but if you cannot, try the answers posted here.

Comment: please post the query that you have used

Comment: See my post and try it

Comment: I cant see your post

Comment: My post was not covering some cases. You should go ahead with the answer posted by @pim

Comment: I re-posted my hints just in case you want to see what I had tested

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `CAST()` or `TRY_CAST()` instead:

```
declare @test nvarchar(8) = '12345678'
select cast(@test as bigint) -- errors on failure
select try_cast(@test as bigint) -- returns null on failure
```

Also, important to point out the `ISNUMERIC()` isn't perfect. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql):

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($). For a complete list of currency symbols, see money and smallmoney (Transact-SQL).

For this reason I don't think the logical check is of value here. Best to use `TRY_CAST()` on all values, regardless of the presence of characters and handle the null response in a predictable manner.

Comment: Yeah MS missed the boat when naming ISNUMERIC. It should have been something like IsCastableToAnyDataTypeThatIsVaguelyANumber

Comment: looks like that is the case. for instance $123 is numeric per IsNumberic function but it is not cast-able. + or - sign did not cause an issue though

Comment: @FLICKER `'$123'` is castable to a numeric type: `select cast('$123' as money)`.  It's just not castable to *all* numeric types.

Comment: @BaconBits, thanks for mentioning, as there are many combinations, we can say this is not very helpful function or it has it's own usage ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue I come across frequently.  The reason you are getting the error has to do with the order in which the Query Engine is parsing the query.  Essentially it is trying to do the convert before the filter.

As mentioned in pim's answer, you can resolve this by using a try_cast, or if you are using an earlier version of SQL server you can wrap a case statement around it:

```
select CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@test) = 1 THEN CONVERT(bigint, @test) ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: I thought the `WHERE` was logically processed before the `SELECT`? If this were true, wouldn't you be able to reference computations from the `SELECT` in the `WHERE`?

Comment: But you can get a LOT of false positives from ISNUMERIC that won't cast correctly. Things 1e3. Or $3.4,

Comment: pim, in theory the where clause should always be processed, however SQL server does magic to make it faster, but sometimes the magic backfires.  I have had SP's that ran without a problem for years, then the data was updated and the update statistics changed the way that SQL processed the query.

Answer (score 1):

I tried below query and did not get error. I tested on SQL 2012 and 2014.

```
with c as (
    select 'A0001001' as acc union all
    select 'A0001002' as acc union all
    select 'A0001003' as acc union all
    select '/0005856' as acc union all
    select '!0005046' as acc union all
    select '~0005872' as acc union all
    select 'A.005698' as acc union all
    select 'A/005623' as acc union all
    select 'A./00578' as acc union all
    select './214536' as acc
)
select isnumeric(acc), convert(bigint, acc)
from c
where isnumeric(acc) = 1
```

Please try this on your database to see if you get any error or not.

This should be a comment but it's too long to add into comment. Hope it helps you figure out your issue.